# Determinant of a matrix with different cases for its entries

Tags: matrix

I am beginner in mathematica. I have the following question:

Assume we have a matrix and some of its entries are nonzero and we know which one are. But the nonzero entries can be three different values and we want to calculate the determinant of the matrix for all different cases. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at `SparseArray` and `Det`. If the matrix is very large, the LU-decomposition provided by `LinearSolve` might help. Moreover, how large is the matrix (number of rows/columns and number of nonzero entries)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Det is always zero

```
 mat = ConstantArray[0, {5, 5}]

Thread[{mat[[1, 2]], mat[[1, 4]], mat[[2, 3]], mat[[2, 5]], 
   mat[[3, 1]], mat[[3, 4]], mat[[4, 4]], mat[[5, 2]]} = 
  RandomChoice[{a, b, c}, 8]]


MatrixForm@mat

Det[mat]
```

Comment: This seems to be a comment on the earlier answer by @Henrik-Schumacher

Answer (score 5):

Here a test example with a `SparseArray` that is actually dense. For large matrices, `Det` might be not the best choice (I am not sure, probably, `Det` is already implemented very cleverly. An alternative can be obtained from the LU factorization provided by `LinearSolve`.

```
n = 12;
SeedRandom[123];
A = SparseArray[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}]];

sol = LinearSolve[A];
det = Times[
  Times @@ Diagonal[sol["getU"]],
  Times @@ Diagonal[sol["getL"]]
  ]
Det[A]
```

> -1.86164
>
> -1.86164

**Edit**

In your particular case, you can build the matrix with your desired sparsity pattern but with arbitrary symbolic values `a[1]`, ... ,`a[8]` as follows:

```
pat = {{1, 2}, {1, 4} , {2, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 1} , {3, 4}, {4, 4}, {5, 2}};
vals = Array[a, Length[pat]];
A = SparseArray[pat -> vals, {5, 5}]
```

Mathematica tells us that a matrix with this sparsity pattern cannot be invertible; its determinant is always zero:

```
Det[A]
```

> 0

Comment: Thank you all. I think i asked my question ambiguous. The matrix is not huge.

Comment: Okay, then `Det` should do the job.

Comment: Thank you all. I think i asked my question ambiguous. The matrix is not huge. Assume we have a 5 by 5 matrix and the entries (1,2) (1,4) (2,3) (2,5) (3,1) (3,4) (4,4) (5,2) are nonzero and the values of these entries can be a,b or c. I want to calculate Det of these matrices for all cases that can happen for nonzero entries. Thank you